# Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P01: missing FROM-clause entry for table "t"

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working a asp.net core WebApi 5.0 project.

I am trying to filter AccommodationCode and rate from samples table

Example :
I send `HOTEL` as a AccommodationCode through query, then I should get only `HOTEL` as AccommodationCode. ( This is working fine)

**But When I try to get rate=3, the list of samples = 0.
also I got this error in debug console
`missing FROM-clause entry for table "t"`**

Query.cs

```
string[] incomingRates = new String[0];
string[] incomingAccommodation = new String[0];
  // removed some

if (request.AccommodationCode != "" && request.AccommodationCode != null)
            {
                incomingAccommodation = request.AccommodationCode.Split(',');
            }

if (request.Rates != "" && request.Rates != null)
            {
                incomingRates = request.Rates.Split(',');
            }

var samples = await _context.Samples
                .Where(i => (i.DestinationCode == request.Destination))
                .Select(i => new SampleListSampleVm
                {
                    Code = i.Code,
                    AccommodationCode = i.AccommodationCode,
                    CategoryCode = i.Category.SimpleCode.ToString(),
                })
                .Where(i => 
                ((incomingAccommodation.Length > 0) ? (incomingAccommodation.Contains(i.AccommodationCode)) : (i.AccommodationCode != ""))  // this line is working fine
               &&  ((incomingRates.Length > 0) ? (incomingRates.Contains(i.CategoryCode)) : (i.CategoryCode != ""))  // Error occurs when I add this line
                )
                .OrderByDescending(i => i.Code)
                .PaginatedListAsync(request.PageNumber, request.PageSize);
```

Sample.cs

```
public int Code { get; set; }        
public string CategoryCode { get; set; }
public string AccommodationCode { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
```

Category.cs

```
   public class Category 
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }

        public int SimpleCode { get; set; }
    }
```

SampleListSampleVm.cs

```
 public class SampleListSampleVm
    {
        public int Code { get; set; }

        public string AccommodationCode { get; set; }

        public int CategoryCode { get; set; }
    }
```

If comment this line `((incomingRates.Length > 0) ? (incomingRates.Contains(i.CategoryCode)) : (i.CategoryCode != ""))` then works fine.

And, I got response with `categoryCode`

```
"code": 396138,
    "categoryCode": "3",`
    "accommodationCode": "HOTEL",
```

Why this error occurs?  `missing FROM-clause entry for table "t"` (AccommodationCode filter is working but categoryCode filter is not working)

Comment: Why do you torture yourself writing complex if-statements in the where clause, when you can make the where clause optional per parameter required? P.S. `if(request.Rates != "" && request.Rates != null)` => `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Rates))`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for comment. I will change it. And, that is not my issue, my issue is in this line `((incomingRates.Length > 0) ? (incomingRates.Contains(i.CategoryCode)) : (i.CategoryCode != ""))`. If you know the solution please help me

Comment: Didn't claim its an issue, it's more readable and does the same. Try whats suggested in the first part of the comment.

Comment: Yeah, I tried and I will follow in future. Thank you.